# Fortran Error: Rank mismatch in array reference (2/1)

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, mingw-w64

i am looking for your help on this where i kept on getting an error at variables in do loops: Rank mismatch in array reference (2/1).
I am new at Fortran and still couldnt completely understand creating two dimensional array and that is where i got the error. 
I am basically trying to create 2000x25000 array for h,u,A,B,C and its derivatives. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
      program HW5
    implicit none
    real::g,W,L,h0,V0,Cf_,T_,H_,deltat,cycl,deltax,Nx,Nt
    !integer::i,j,Nt,Nx
    real,dimension(2000)::x,xmid,h,u,A,B,C
    real,dimension(25000)::t,tmid,hh,uH,AH,BH,CH,hf,uF,AF,BF,CF
    integer::matrix(2000,25000),i,j !two dimensional real array
    real,parameter::pi=4*atan(1.0)
g=9.81  !gravitational acceleration
W=1  !channel width
L=20  !channel length
h0=12  !initial water depth
V0=0  !initial velocity
Cf_=0.005  !friction coefficient
T_=2  !wave period
H_=1  !wave amplitude
deltat=0.0008
cycl=10
Nx=2001
deltax=L/(Nx-1)
Nt=(cycl*T_/(deltat))+1
x(1)=0
do i=1,Nx-1
    x(i+1)=x(i)+deltax
    xmid(i)=x(i)+deltax/2
end do
t(1)=0
do j=1,Nt-1
    t(j+1)=t(j)+deltat
    tmid(j)=t(j)+deltat/2
end do
do j=1,Nt
do i=1,Nx
    h(i,j)=h0
    u(i,j)=V0
    A(i,j)=u(i,j)*h(i,j)
    B(i,j)=(h(i,j)*(u(i,j))**2)+(g*(h(i,j))**2)/2
    C(i,j)=(Cf_*u(i,j)*abs(u(i,j))*(W+2*h(i,j)))/(2*W)
end do
end do
do j=1,Nt-1
    do i=Nx,1,-1
        if (i==Nx) then
            hh(i,j)=h0+(H_/2)*sin(2*pi*tmid(j)/T_)
            AH(i,j)=A(i,j)-(deltat/(2*deltax))*(B(i,j)-B(i-1,j))-(deltat*C(i,j)/2)
            uH(i,j)=AH(i,j)/hh(i,j)
            BH(i,j)=hh(i,j)*uH(i,j)**2+(g*hh(i,j)**2)/2
            CH(i,j)=(Cf_*uH(i,j)*abs(uH(i,j))*(W+2*hh(i,j)))/(2*W)
        elseif (i==1) then
                hh(i,j)=h(i,j)-((deltat/(2*deltax))*(A(i+1,j)-A(i,j)))
                uH(i,j)=AH(i,j)/hh(i,j)
                BH(i,j)=hh(i,j)*((uH(i,j))**2)+(g*(hh(i,j))**2)/2
                CH(i,j)=(Cf_*abs(uH(i,j))*(W+2*hh(i,j)))/(2*W)
        else
                hh(i,j)=0.5*(h(i+1,j)+h(i-1,j))-(deltat/(4*deltax))*(A(i+1,j)-A(i-1,j))
                AH(i,j)=0.5*(A(i+1,j)+A(i-1,j))-(deltat/(4*deltax))*(B(i+1,j)-B(i-1,j))-deltat*(C(i,j))/2
                uH(i,j)=AH(i,j)/hh(i,j)
                BH(i,j)=hh(i,j)*((uH(i,j))**2)+(g*(hh(i,j))**2)/2
                CH(i,j)=(Cf_*uH(i,j)*abs(uH(i,j))*(W+2*hh(i,j)))/(2*W)
                end if
                end do
                end do
do j=1,Nt-1
    do i=Nx,1,-1
        if (i==Nx) then
            hf(i,j+1)=h0+(H_/2)*sin(2*pi*tmid(j+1)/T)
            AF(i,j+1)=A(i,j)-(deltat/(deltax))*(BH(i,j)-BH(i-1,j))-(deltat*C(i,j)/2)
            uF(i,j+1)=AF(i,j+1)/hf(i,j+1)
            BF(i,j+1)=hf(i,j+1)*uF(i,j+1)**2+(g*hf(i,j+1)**2)/2
            CF(i,j+1)=(Cf_*uF(i,j+1)*abs(uF(i,j+1))*(W+2*hf(i,j+1)))/(2*W)
        elseif (i==1) then
                hf(i,j+1)=hh(i,j)-((deltat/(deltax))*(AH(i+1,j)-AH(i,j)))
                uF(i,j+1)=AF(i,j+1)/hf(i,j+1)
                BF(i,j+1)=hf(i,j+1)*((uF(i,j+1))**2)+(g*(hf(i,j+1))**2)/2
                CF(i,j+1)=(Cf_*uF(i,j+1)*abs(uF(i,j+1))*(W+2*hf(i,j+1)))/(2*W)
        else
                hf(i,j+1)=hh(i,j)-((deltat/(2*deltax))*(AH(i+1,j)-AH(i-1,j)))
                AF(i,j+1)=A(i,j)-(deltat/(2*deltax))*(BH(i+1,j)-BH(i-1,j))-(deltat*CH(i,j)/2)
                uF(i,j+1)=AF(i,j+1)/hf(i,j+1)
                BF(i,j+1)=hf(i,j+1)*((uF(i,j+1))**2)+(g*(hf(i,j+1))**2)/2
                CF(i,j+1)=(Cf_*uF(i,j+1)*abs(uF(i,j+1))*(W+2*hf(i,j+1)))/(2*W)
                end if
                end do
                end do
end program HW5
```

Comment: The rank of an entity is the number of dimensions it may have.  For example, you have `real, dimenstion(2000) :: h`, which is an array, a rank 1 entity.  In the nested do-loop, you `h(i,j) = h0` where you're referencing `h` as-if it is a rank 2 entity.  You cannot do that, and this type of error appears in several places.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. You should always search first. There was already a an answered question with the error message in the title here.